# Cache Busting Static Images Using Less

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching, less

**Situation:**

I'm attempting to add cache-busting query parameters to my less files. Declaring a time-stamp in the less file and appending it to each background css property:

```
@cache-version: `( new Date() ).getTime()` ;

background: url('images/icons.png?version=@{cache-version}')
```

Results show the bust-string appending to the image with a version number in the Network Tab Chrome Dev Tool....

```
/assets/images/icons.png?version=1429402449860
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that upon doing a "normal-reload" on the chrome browser, it's still showing "from cache". Which is not grabbing the static images from the server.

**Question:**

How can I grab the static images fresh from the server?

**Edit:**

I've meticulously used this approach with no luck:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2643-cache-busting-css-images-with-less-css.htm

I'm thinking of try creating a grunt-task but unsure if that will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that upon doing a "normal-reload" on the chrome browser, it's > still showing "from cache". Which is not grabbing the static images from the > server.

Less compiles into static CSS, so you will need to recompile your CSS (changing the cache time) before reloading your browser. Also when you are using Less in browser does Less cache your Less files (and so uses possible the old cache time). For Less in browser set the `environment` option to `debug` to prevent caching.